# The Type or Namespace "MyServiceClient" Could not be Found

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, using

I've just completed [this wcf duplex tutorial](http://putridparrot.com/blog/wcf-duplex/), but upon going over my code I encountered this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description   Line
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MyServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ClientSide 15
```

My usings all seem to be in order, and I've googled this error numerous times with no luck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ClientSide
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InstanceContext callback = new InstanceContext(new ClientCallback());
            MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(callback);
            client.Open();
            client.Register();
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is MyServiceClient a type or a namespace?

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Did you ever actually add the service reference? (The code sample as given is insufficient to actually duplicate your error)

Comment: Yes, I did add the service reference, which was one of the earlier problems I had as the tutorial didn't specify that step. I am unsure as to whether MyServiceClient is a type similar to ServiceHost or if I am supposed to specify a specific file in place of it. When I begin typing, the autocomplete pops up with MyServiceClient, but the icon to the left of it is a red 'X'.

Comment: It appears to me that the tutorial does specify that step under the section "Create the client".  Regardless, my first suspicion is that you simply named the client differently then the tutorial did, so just need to change your code to use the actual name for your client.  However, you don't show any of that information in your question.

Comment: Oh, right you are.

I've named my client as the tutorial specifies, and it never says anything about naming any sort of file 'MyServiceClient' so I'm not entirely sure what I could mis-name. I will re-read the tutorial again thought, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `MyServiceClient` should be the name of the client class generated when you did "Add Service Reference".

To verify the name of the generated class, in windows explorer navigate to the directory containing your service references (typically e.g. `<ProjectName>\Service References\<ServiceReferenceName>`, and open the file `Reference.cs`

Inside of Reference.cs, look for a class that inherits from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`.  The derived class is the your service client class that you should use to interact with the web service.

So, for example, if `Reference.cs` contained

```
public partial class BlahServiceSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<global::MyProject.MyService.BlahServiceSoap>, global::MyProject.MyService.BlahServiceSoap
```

Note, that depending on the reference, it could be a different subclass of [System.ServiceModel.ClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you see in the Reference.cs file.  Since this question is specifically about the duplex client, you would see [System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then your service class would be `BlahServiceSoapClient`, so you would do

```
BlahServiceSoapClient client = new BlahServiceSoapClient(callback);
```

Comment: I've found the specified line within my Reference.cs. _public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<Client.MyService.IMyService>, Client.MyService.IMyService_ Oddly enough, it seems that MyServiceClient is correct.

Comment: @user5389897 Check the namespace that `MyServiceClient` is inside of (still `Reference.cs`) - you will need to import that namespace.  Typically it is something like `namespace ProjectName.ServiceName`

Comment: Thanks to your help, I've found the problem. The MyServiceClient class was under a slightly different namespace than my main program file(Client.MyService as opposed to Client). Adding a new using directive fixed the problem nicely. Thanks again!